# How to resolve error loading FirebaseOptions from resource? (PlatformException: java.lang.Exception)

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a simple signin/signup application with Firebase, but I'm encountering the following error.
Already tried flutter clean .

> E/flutter ( 4727):
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load
> FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml
> correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception:
> Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have
> defined values.xml correctly. E/flutter ( 4727): at
> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$optionsFromResource$4$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:207)
> E/flutter ( 4727): at
> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown
> Source:4) E/flutter ( 4727): at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/flutter ( 4727): at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/flutter ( 4727): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) E/flutter
> ( 4727): , null) E/flutter ( 4727): #0
> FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource
> (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
> E/flutter ( 4727): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 4727): #1
> MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
> (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
> E/flutter ( 4727): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 4727): #2
> Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
> E/flutter ( 4727): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 4727): #3
> main (package:firebase_signup/main.dart:7:3) E/flutter ( 4727):
> <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 4727):

**Login Code Snippet:**

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//Login section

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key); // key düzeltildi

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();

  signin()async{
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email.text,
      password: password.text,
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login")),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), // Padding'in yanına virgül eklendi
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: email,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter email",
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: password,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter password",
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: ()=>signin(),
                child: Text("Login")
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Wrapper Code Snippet:**

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_signup/homepage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_signup/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Wrapper> createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomePage();
          } else {
            return Login();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage Code Snippet:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; // Cupertino import yerine Material import edildi
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; // FirebaseAuth import edildi

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); // key düzeltildi

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  signout() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("asd")), // AppBar yazım hatası düzeltildi
      body: Center(
        child: Text('${user!.email}'), // Kullanıcının e-postası eklendi
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActi`your text`onButton(
        onPressed: () => signout(), // Fonksiyon çağrısı düzgün şekilde yapıldı
        child:Icon(Icons.login_rounded) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't run/complete these setup steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Answer (score 0):

you should update your code
should  call `Firebase.initializeApp` before any firebase related call also add option parameter also with it. Better configure through firebase cli will auto generate files

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'key',
    appId: 'id',
    messagingSenderId: 'sendid',
    projectId: 'myapp',
    storageBucket: 'myapp-b9yt18.appspot.com',
  )
    );
```

created new app, and configured it with cli mode it will generate the options file for all platforms.
Just add `google-services.json` won't be enough from flutte 3.19 it seems

[firebase cli config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=en&authuser=0#install_the_firebase_cli)

once the files are generated your firebaseinit code should look like this

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
);
```